# Run method to end without caring for exceptions

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say you have the following method:

```
public void Install()
{
    CreateItem(Item1)
    CreateItem(Item2)
    CreateItem(Item3)
}
```

where `CreateItem` will throw a `ItemAlreadyExistsException` if the item already exists, but you want execution to continue to the other two even if that exception is thrown, so you'd probably do something similar to this:

```
public void Install()
{
    var itemsColl = new[] {Item1, Item2, Item3};

    foreach (var item in itemsColl)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateItem(item);
        }
        catch (ItemAlreadyExistsException e)
        {
            // Do nothing or handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say you also have an `Uninstall()` method that does the opposite - deletes the items - and that you also have a `Repair()` method that just calls to `Uninstall()` and then `Install()` - with one small difference: on `Repair()` because you just had a call to `Uninstall()` before you calling `Install()` you *know* that the items should never exist (if they did, they would have gotten deleted by the `Uninstall()` call) which means now you do care about the `ItemAlreadyExistsExceptions` and you no longer want to catch them.

In this particular simple example the body of `Install()` is small/simple enough that it could just be copied to `Repair()` (although this would create duplication of code), but how would one go about creating something that works for a more complex example without creating duplication of code?

One thing I can think of is creating something like:

```
public void Install()
{
    InternalInstall(false);
}

private void InternalInstall(bool throwOnError)
{
    var itemsColl = new[] {Item1, Item2, Item3};

    foreach (var item in itemsColl)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateItem(item);
        }
        catch (ItemAlreadyExistsException e)
        {
            if (throwOnError)
                throw;
        }
    }
}

public void Repair()
{
    Uninstall();
    InternalInstall(true);
}
```

But having a parameter decide whether to throw or not is not a very good idea as stated here (even if this is a private method): [Throw/do-not-throw an exception based on a parameter - why is this not a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624647/throw-do-not-throw-an-exception-based-on-a-parameter-why-is-this-not-a-good-id)

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Consider to make non-throwing version of method, e.g. `bool TryCreateItem()`.

Comment: Probably opinionated but `CreateItem` really shouldn't throw an exception here, since it obviously is _not_ "exceptional". But anyway: You are on track with `Install` and `InternalInstall`: move the try/catch to `Install` instead of `InternalInstall`.

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think only someone who's never experienced the "fun" of a VB application with `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` set would think to suggest this. Agree with Fidor that these exceptions appear to be [Vexing](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I used to work for a company where their main business was the automation of converting old VB6 applications to c# application - which basically means you're getting VB6 written in c# syntax (No, you can't imagine the horror unless you've been there) - methods with `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` created  methods where every code line was executed as a lambda expression sent to a class called "ErrorManager". A true nightmare for maintenance, as can be expected - you don't even want to know what they came up with for "ON ERROR GOTO LABLE_NAME"....

Comment: I agree with all the previous comments - "ItemAlreadyExistsException" - Should this even be an exception?

Comment: Ok, first of all I appreciate all of the comments, but regarding whether `ItemAlreadyExistsException` being an exception, please remember this is pseudocode, this is not the actual exception being thrown and - short of wrapping it in another method - I have no control over the exception it happens in .NET code. So please let's stop discussing whether the exception should be there to begin with or not :)

Comment: @computeka Fair enough. Just a tip for future questions: In such cases, it's worthwhile noting in the question that you have no control over the API you consume (i.e. you cannot change anything about `CreateItem`).

Comment: well, the referenced link is quite old.  It was as subjective then as it is now; also, it was really qualified to the scoped and use of `bool` type specifically.  I think the approach here is fine for a one off, but I would prefer a policy based approach to conditional exception handling, and therefore would look at libs like polly for fault tolerance and resilience work;  having said that, I do think this topic is better suited for another exchange site.

Comment: @Fildor if I move the try/catch from `InternalInstall` to `Install` then it will silently fail on the first exception - as oppose to continuing to the remaining items.

Comment: @computeka Yeah, it's more to that than just moving the try/catch. I've been a little imprecise on that one, sorry. I think we need to also move the iteration. As is, `Repair` iterates 2 times: First in `Uninstall`, then `Install`. Wouldn't it make more sense to iterate `Uninstall(itemN), Install(itemN);`? Then exceptions can be handled here on item basis - am I making sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think, I'd do it like this

```
IEnumerable<Item> Install(){
    var failedItems = new List<Item>();

    // assuming items is a list of Items on class level
    foreach( var item in items )
    {
       try{ CreateItem(item); }
       catch(ItemAlreadyExistsException ){
          failedItems.Add(item);
       }
    }
    return failedItems;
}
```

Something similar for `Uninstall`, and finally

```
IEnumerable<Item> Repair(){
    var failedItems = new List<Item>();

    // assuming items is a list of Items on class level
    foreach( var item in items )
    {
       try
       { 
          DeleteItem(item);
          CreateItem(item); 
       }
       catch(ItemAlreadyExistsException ){
          failedItems.Add(item);
       }
    }
    return failedItems;
}
```

Of course you immediately see where the code duplication is now and how you could improve from there on.

Maybe a little like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Item> GuardedIterationOfItems( Action<Item> action )
{
     var failedItems = new List<Item>();

    // assuming items is a list of Items on class level
    foreach( var item in items )
    {
       try{ 
          action(item); 
       }
       catch(ItemAlreadyExistsException ){
          failedItems.Add(item);
       }
    }
    return failedItems;
}

IEnumerable<Item> Install()
{
   return GuardedIterationOfItems( CreateItem );
}

IEnumerable<Item> UnInstall()
{
   return GuardedIterationOfItems( DeleteItem );
}

IEnumerable<Item> Repair()
{
   return GuardedIterationOfItems( x => {
         DeleteItem(x);
         CreateItem(x);
   });
}
```

Disclaimer: Untested and maybe in need of threadsafety measures if it should be.

Comment: ah.. yes.. adding the exception to a collection slipped my mind altogether when I initially read this question.   in which case, I think I would throw an aggregate exception using that list, not return it.

Comment: @BrettCaswell this is returning a list of items, for which an exception is thrown, though. Not the exceptions.