# Nullable Reference Types and throwOnError pattern

Tags: throw, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to fully decorate an API that uses (what I call) the `throwOnError` pattern.
I know some people dislike it but this is not the point: it is used by people far more clever than me, for instance in the `Assembly.GetType` method:

`public virtual Type? GetType(string name, bool throwOnError)`

I'm a little bit disappointed: it seems that currently (C#9/net5), it is not possible to state that the return cannot be null as long as throwOnError is true. Something like:  `[return: NotNullIfTrue( "throwOnError" )]`.

The source here is (sadly) naked: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Assembly.cs,106

Does anyone has a solution to this? Should we wait for a *NotNullIfTrue* attribute?

PS: I don't want to use [DoesNotReturnIf(true)] since this is obvisoulsy a too strong assertion.

Comment: Framework designers make mistakes too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624647/throw-do-not-throw-an-exception-based-on-a-parameter-why-is-this-not-a-good-id

Comment: I respectfully disagree about this "DONT" when you're writing low-level code (lib) that is not aware of the error strategy above (application level) and must make everybody happy. But this is not the point here :).

Comment: I created this yesterday: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6932

Comment: Thank you (I upvoted and commented it).